# vim plugin taskwiki can't import libraries

Tags: python, vim

I am tring to start to use `vimwiki/taskwiki/taskwarrior` in my workflow. (MacOS Catalina 10.15.6 (19G2021)/ Python 3.8.5)

When I run <\ww> to start the `vimwiki` in `vim`, and `vim` throws out the warning:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/xitaoliu/.vim/plugged/taskwiki/ftplugin/vimwiki/taskwiki.vim:
line   29:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/xitaoliu/.vim/plugged/taskwiki/taskwiki/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    from taskwiki import cache as cache_module
  File "/Users/xitaoliu/.vim/plugged/taskwiki/taskwiki/cache.py", line 5, in <module>
    from taskwiki import preset
  File "/Users/xitaoliu/.vim/plugged/taskwiki/taskwiki/preset.py", line 5, in <module>
    from taskwiki import util
  File "/Users/xitaoliu/.vim/plugged/taskwiki/taskwiki/util.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tasklib
ImportError: No module named tasklib
```

I am using vim-plug to manage the vim plugins. here are the plugins list in my vim

```
- vimwiki: OK                                |~                                           
- vim-plugin-AnsiEsc: OK                     |~                                           
- tagbar: OK                                 |~                                           
- vim-tmux: OK                               |~                                           
- tasklib: OK                                |~                                           
- taskwiki: OK
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the projects [GitHub README](https://github.com/tools-life/taskwiki/blob/master/README.md), you have to install the `tasklib` python package with [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/). You can do this by navigating to the `taskwiki` repository on your machine and running:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Hi Jake, Thanks for your response. 

I have done this already, but vim still throws out the same error.

To be specific, I did this:
Go to the directory where the requirements.txt exits, and run "sudo pip ..."
```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/libexec/setuptools/docs/ 
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Also make sure that you are using the same python version as vim does.
I had a similar issue where a package was not found and it turned out the system version of python was 3.6, while vim (neovim) used 3.7.
So I changed the system version to 3.7 temporarily with
`sudo update-alternatives --config python3` (works on Ubuntu), ran the install again and after that everything was fixed.